# list of tuples to rdd with count using map reduce pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an rdd similar to following:

```
[('C3', [{'Item': 'Shirt', 'Color ': 'Black', 'Size': '32','Price':'2500'}, {'Item': 'Sweater', 'Color ': 'Red', 'Size': '35', 'Price': '1000'},  {'Item': 'Jeans', 'Color ': 'Yellow', 'Size': '30', 'Price': '1500'}]), ('C1', [{'Item': 'Shirt', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Price': '2000'}, {'Item': 'Saree', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Price': '1500'}, {'Item': 'Saree', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Price': '1500'}, {'Item': 'Jeans', 'Color ': 'Yellow', 'Size': '30', 'Price': '1500'}])]
```

We can create above the rdd by:

```
sc.parallelize([('C3', [{'Item': 'Shirt', 'Color ': 'Black', 'Size': '32','Price':'2500'}, {'Item': 'Sweater', 'Color ': 'Red', 'Size': '35', 'Price': '1000'},  {'Item': 'Jeans', 'Color ': 'Yellow', 'Size': '30', 'Price': '1500'}]), ('C1', [{'Item': 'Shirt', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Price': '2000'}, {'Item': 'Saree', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Price': '1500'}, {'Item': 'Saree', 'Color ': 'Green', 'Size': '25', 'Price': '1500'}, {'Item': 'Jeans', 'Color ': 'Yellow', 'Size': '30', 'Price': '1500'}])])
```

I need to create a dataframe/rdd similar to following (I am adding count to all attributes)

```
{'C1': {'Color ': {'Green': 3, 'Yellow': 1},
'Item': {'Jeans': 1, 'Saree': 2, 'Shirt': 1},
'Price': {'1500': 3, '2000': 1},
'Size': {'25': 3, '30': 1}},
'C3': {'Color ': {'Black': 1, 'Red': 1, 'Yellow': 1},
'Item': {'Jeans': 1, 'Shirt': 1, 'Sweater': 1},
'Price': {'1000': 1, '1500': 1, '2500': 1},
'Size': {'30': 1, '32': 1, '35': 1}}}
```

Corresponding dataframe/rdd will be:

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
|custo      |attr                                                                                      
|C1     |Map(Color -> Map(Green -> 3, yellow -> 1), Item -> Map(Jeans -> 1, Saree  -> 2, Shirt ->1),  Price ->  | 
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a udf to collect the counts.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t

def count(c_dict):
    res = {}
    for item in c_dict:
        print(type(item))
        for key in item:
            print(key, item[key])
            if key in res:
                if item[key] in res[key]:
                    res[key][item[key]]+= 1
                else:
                    res[key][item[key]] = 1
            else:
                res[key]={}
                res[key][item[key]] = 1
    return(res)
schema = t.MapType(t.StringType(), t.MapType(t.StringType(), t.IntegerType()))
count_udf = f.udf(count, schema)

df2 = df.withColumn( 'col2' , count_udf(df.col2))
df.collect()
```

result

```
[Row(col1='C3', col2={'Size': {'35': 1, '30': 1, '32': 1}, 'Price': {'2500': 1, '1500': 1, '1000': 1}, 'Item': {'Sweater': 1, 'Jeans': 1, 'Shirt': 1}, 'Color ': {'Red': 1, 'Black': 1, 'Yellow': 1}}),
 Row(col1='C1', col2={'Size': {'25': 3, '30': 1}, 'Price': {'1500': 3, '2000': 1}, 'Item': {'Jeans': 1, 'Saree': 2, 'Shirt': 1}, 'Color ': {'Green': 3, 'Yellow': 1}})]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't add schema like this because, my attribute column can be anything. even the number of item can change. The attribute number and type can change

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I meant instead of size, I can have pattern, which can be a string, may be some other attribute in another type. so I can't define the schema like this. input Dataframe is coming from some other source and it can change always

Comment: Can you show an example where this would not work? Consider the output of `df.withColumn('exploded', f.explode('attr')).select('customer', 'exploded').show(truncate=False)` - you essentially want to group by the customer and combine the dictionaries to get counts.

Comment: @user2805885  It will work in the case you have mentioned. The names for  keys are not hard coded. If your key type is not string you can always cast it to string and count should be either integer or long type.